# Is there a way to get the CSS value of a specific time point on a jquery 'animate' sequence?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I'm looking for a kind of a function that will receive a time value in ms and a reference to a div holding an 'animate' queue and return the CSS values reflecting what this div should be on the passed time point.

For example, if I create the following queue:

```
 $("#someDiv").queue(function (next) {
     $(this).animate({
         left: 600,
         top: 400,
         opacity: 0.5
     }, 300)
         .delay(200);
     next();
 });
```

now, I need a function that will receive 'someDiv' and a time value, and return the css properties that reflect the item on that specific time value: if I pass a time value of '150' then the function should return something like: { left : 300, top: 200, opacity: 0.25 }.  Of course I could calculate these values myself but I was wondering if there's a built in way to do it, for all the CSS properties that can be animated.

Thanks !

Comment: [step option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12415199/jquery-animate-step-function) execute function each animation step

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
setInterval(function () {
    var $sidebar = $('.side-bar');
    if ($sidebar.is(':animated')) return;
    if (condition) {
        $sidebar.animate({
            backgroundColor: "#fff"
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        $sidebar.animate({
            backgroundColor: "#000"
        }, 1000);
    }
}, 20);
```

here is Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yXWPD/

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see how this is relevant to my question... am I missing something?...